# Why does my next.js(13.4.19) never throw a 404 page when using generateStaticParams to create a set of dynamic routes?

Tags: next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing, generatestaticparams

I am trying to achive the most basic functionality of dynamic routing in Next.js using generateStaticParams().
Here is my file strucure:
[image]
here is the code from ./app/[route]/page.tsx:

```js
export default function Page({ params }: { params: {route: string} }){

  const route = params.route ;

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{`Staticlly Generated Route ${route}`}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export function generateStaticParams() {
  return [{route: 'one'}, {route: 'two'}, {route: 'three'}];
}
```

This issue is, regardless what url is entered it resolves with the route as the route parameter to Page component:
[image]
The goal is to have it to return a 404 if the route is anything not returned by generateStaticParams, in this case, /one, /two, or /three

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The answer is documented on the [Route Segment Config](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config) page in Next.js docs

by default "Dynamic segments not included in generateStaticParams are generated on demand."

[image]

so "by directly exporting the following variables:" which is in our case is dynamicParams, we can make "Dynamic segments not included in generateStaticParams return a 404"

i added:
`export const dynamicParams = false`
in my `app/[route]/page.tsx`
It also worked as an export in app/layout.tsx.

[image]